# How to design a database in which there are many users and each has a list of multiple contacts?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So far all I have configured is a table for users where each user has a unique `user_id`. However, I need to store a list of contacts for each user. This would only need to contain the user_id of each contact. However, I'm faced with a design challenge.

Should I create a table for each user in which to store that users list of contacts? Is this a scalable solution?

Or should I create one table with two columns, `user_id` and `contact_id`, looking something like this:

```
------------------------------------
| user_id (INT) | contact_id (INT) |
------------------------------------
|    10001      |       9945       |
|    10001      |       2239       |
|    10002      |       9636       |
------------------------------------
```

I'm afraid that if I went with the second option, the lack of unique indexing and the sheer size of the table would eventually make even `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id=10001;` because every entry would need to be iterated over each time.

What is the best way to organize these data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single normalised table is absolutely the correct approach.

You're worried about its performance, due to a concern about "lack of indexing".

Lack of indexing? Why lack of indexing?

Make your primary key `(user_id,contact_id)` — which makes sense semantically an' all — and that's all you need.

Never, *ever* have a variable number of tables. "A table for each user" is when you get booted from my team. ;)

Comment: agreed with never having a variable number of tables!

Comment: Just for learning purposes, the primary key would be the unique combination of user and contact? That's so simple! I had no idea primary keys could span multiple columns. I'm new to this. Thank you!

Comment: @CannonPalms: There you go. :) For the record, being new is not really any "excuse", since this is mentioned in the very first line on [the relevant manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html).

Comment: Unaware that this was the solution to my question, I wasn't searching for information on primary keys specifically. Is the first thing you do when playing around with a new technology (new to you, not new to the world) read the manual from start to end?

Comment: @CannonPalms: Yes, of course it is! That's why the manual exists... Why, what's _your_ first step? :/

Answer (score 1):

The second way with the "pivot" table is the best way and best practice for normalization. You would also want to make foreign key relations with indexes to the proper tables and columns.

Comment: So additionally, a table holding the `start_index` of contacts for a specific user in the `contacts` table, where when a contact was added or deleted, the index would be updated?

Comment: @CannonPalms: Er, no. Databases have done that for you since the 1960s. Look up "indexes" in your MySQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm afraid that if I went with the second option, the lack of unique
>   indexing and the sheer size of the table would eventually make even
>   SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id=10001; because every entry would
>   need to be iterated over each time.

An index on user_id will eliminate this problem.  Rather than iterating, it will use search algorithms that perform well even over large numbers of records.  A clustered index, if `where user_id=` is the most common type of query, will make performance even better.

The first option, a table per user, is absolutely the worst way you could ever do it.